# How the mechanism of custom delegate and Predefined(apple provided) delegate differ?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

When we use any predefined delegates like UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, we are not calling the required/optional methods explicitly or programatically. But incase of custom delegates we are calling the delegate methods using delegate object. Just want to know is there any difference between the mechanism of custom delegate and predefined delegate?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question? Is this about SWIFT? Not sure this can be answered the way you ask.

Comment: I am asking about objective c.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no programmatic difference between letting Interface Builder / Xcode automatically specify your delegates or you manually assigning your delegates in code or Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got the question clarified by one of my friends :)